# Split array into two on the basis of value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to split array into two on the basis of value.

For example

```
Array(
    [25] => Korea Strawberry (Pkt) 250g
    [26] => *8887187338308
    [27] => PROM Mix 2@38.9G
    [28] => 19.90*2 38.90 Z
    [29] => 0.45*2
    [30] => 
    [31] => 
    [32] => Total with GST @ 6%
    [33] => Rounding
    [34] => Total
    [35] => Tender
    [36] => Master 0003 App: 807946
    [37] => Change
    [38] => GST Analysis Goods Tax Amount
    [39] => S = 6%
    [40] => Item 3
    [41] => Qty 4
    [42] => Total Saving 9.44
    [43] => 56.94
)
```

I want it to be in two parts. One all the values before `Total with GST @ 6%` second all remaining values.

How can I do that. I tried `array_diff()` and other methods but didn't work as what I want.

Comment: Look at `array_search()` and `array_slice()`

Comment: @Kapil Sharma, do you want to preserve the keys or the resulting array may be reindexed?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the key number for `Total with GST @ 6%` using `array_search` then split the array using 2 loops.

```
$array = Array(
    [25] => Korea Strawberry (Pkt) 250g
    [26] => *8887187338308
    [27] => PROM Mix 2@38.9G
    [28] => 19.90*2 38.90 Z
    [29] => 0.45*2
    [30] => 
    [31] => 
    [32] => Total with GST @ 6%
    [33] => Rounding
    [34] => Total
    [35] => Tender
    [36] => Master 0003 App: 807946
    [37] => Change
    [38] => GST Analysis Goods Tax Amount
    [39] => S = 6%
    [40] => Item 3
    [41] => Qty 4
    [42] => Total Saving 9.44
    [43] => 56.94
);

$value = 'Total with GST @ 6%'; //This can be dynamically filled
$split = array_search($value, $array)

for($i=0; $i<$split; $i++) {
    $newArray1[] = $array[$i];
}
for($i=$split; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    $newArray2[] = $array[$i];
}
unset($array); //Now it's split we can unset the $array variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Just be careful about using it on associative arrays, or arrays with arbitrary numerical keys.